# Android : Facebook No User Install

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-graph-api, installation

We have integrated `Facebook` on our `Android` app, and we do not know `Facebook` can't track its installs. The app is already live for 2 months, and we still cannot see the installs.

We just followed the tutorial, [click here](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/getting-started/facebook-sdk-for-android/3.0/), on how to integrate it. The app is also on `iOS`, and the installs are being tracked correctly, see the image below.

[image]

Any ideas?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I added `com.facebook.Settings.publishInstallAsync(context, applicationId)` on my `Activity`'s `onResume()` method.